# rspec - before(:all) Hook ignored when running all tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    cleaner.strategy = :truncation
    cleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    cleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

And one of the tests:

```
  require 'rspec'

    describe 'Test of all Listing parameters' do
      before(:all) do
        populate_from_yaml('spec/sample_data/listing_param_filtering_data.yaml')
      end

      it 'filter by active listing' do
        params = make_params(userId: 'users-1', limit: 100)
        listings = request_shuffler(params)

        expect(listings).not_to include('listing-inactive')
        expect(listings).to include('listing-active-all-empty')
      end

      it 'filter by doorman' do
        params = make_params(userId: 'users-1', limit: 100, doorman: true)
        listings = request_shuffler(params)

        expect(listings).to match_array(['listing-param-doorman'])
      end
      # and so on
   end
```

When I run test specifing test name everything works fine

```
rspec spec/test_spec.rb
```

But if I execute all tests:

```
rspec spec
```

I got errors:

```
Test of all Listing parameters filter by active listing
Failure/Error: populate_from_yaml('spec/sample_data/listing_param_filtering_data.yaml')
Sequel::UniqueConstraintViolation:
    PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "agents_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(agent-1) already exists.
Debug data ...

Test of all Listing parameters filter by doorman
Failure/Error: populate_from_yaml('spec/sample_data/listing_param_filtering_data.yaml')
Sequel::UniqueConstraintViolation:
    PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "agents_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(agent-1) already exists.
Debug data ...

...
```

It looks like rspec just ignoring config.around(:each) stopping to clean database, ignores before(:all) hook and trying to populate database one each example... Any ideas?

I'm using
ruby-2.2.0p0
rspec-3.2.0

btw it's not rails

Comment: do you have a `.rspec` file?

Comment: Yeah, content:
--color
--require spec_helper

Comment: I just followed your suggestion - Got rid of before(:all) hook... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`before(:all)` is evil and is the source of many headaches, so many rspec has considered multiple times [to remove the command at all](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/573). This block is not wrapped in a transaction, so the data will not be rolled back after the test. You should clear your data in the `after(:all)` block manually.

My personal best practice is to use `before(:all)` only to set up environment variables, global libs configurations ... but never to use it to hit the DB.

I suggest you just change your `before(:all)` for a `before(:each)`.